# Programmatically arrange windows in tabs in Mac Catalyst

Tags: mac-catalyst, uikitformac

I'm using Mac Catalyst to port an iPad app to Mac. I'm able to create multiple windows using:

```
func requestSceneSessionActivation(_ sceneSession: UISceneSession?,  userActivity: NSUserActivity?, options: UIScene.ActivationRequestOptions?, errorHandler: ((Error) -> Void)? = nil)
```

Also, I'm able to arrange the created windows in tab from the application's menu:

```
Application Menu > Window > Merge All Windows
```

But I don't see an option to programmatically do so. I would use [NSWindowTabGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowtabgroup) in AppKit. However, it is not available in [Mac Catalyst](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/mac_catalyst). Please let me know if it is possible yet?